# How does Kafka choose a partition for key?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose the number of partitions is fixed for a topic. And suppose I provide a key --- an array of bytes --- when publishing a message. Kafka will map the key onto a topic partition 0,1,2,3,...N-1.

I'd like to make a function that does the same thing: given N, and the key return the same partition number as would Kafka.

Is this this just (in pseudo-code) murmur3(key) % N?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultPartitioner` uses `murmur3` function to calculate partition for messages with not null keys.

You can just extract *algorithm* and added to your code:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils;
Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
```

Second option is to just use `DefaultPartitioner`:

```java
DefaultPartitioner partitioner = new DefaultPartitioner();
int partition = partitioner.partition(???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. `import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Kafka hashes a key and partition according to that hash value. Here is a helpful diagram and an example on how.

> Utils.abs(java.util.Arrays.hashCode(key.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte])) % numPartitions

[image]

Just found another good example of partitioning!

[image]

Comment: hashCode() isn't consistent over JVM implementations, so that isn't the correct function

Comment: @cricket_007 ah I didn't know. thank you for your help.